# Matching non-[a-zA-Z] characters in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have some strings that need a-strippin':

`ÃœT: 9.996636,76.294363`

Tons of long strings of location codes. A literal regex in PHP won't match them, IE

```
$pattern = /ÃœT:/;
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $row['location']);
```

Won't match/strip anything. (To know it's working, `/T:/` does strip the last bit of that string). What's the encoding error going on here?

Alternately, I would accept a concise way to take out just the numbers.

Comment: You see all of these letters I am typing? They are all pretty weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is all in that format (: followed by a space) you can probably just say:

```
$str = explode(": ", $pattern);
echo($str[1]);
```

It's not the most *elegant* solution *per-se* and I have no idea if this is incredibly slow, but it works for most things. Unless you're hell bent on using regular expressions that is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the /u modifier on your regex to work with unicode